# Do I need to secure a computer from physical attacks when attackers can already harm in many other ways?

Tags: physical, security-theater

Recently, I was working on a computer system for a model railroad club.  This computer system is capable of monitoring and controlling the positions of all the (physical) trains which could be anywhere on the track layout.

However, someone recently came in and criticized the system for not running in a password-protected, locked-down account.  He even went so far as to suggest adding a BIOS password.

However, I countered that argument by saying that anything that someone could do damage by via computer could be done just as easily by picking up a hammer.  By the time that someone would be able to exploit the fact that the computer had no password, they could have already done the same level of damage.

Were his concerns legitimate, or was he taking things too far?

Comment: Is this computer connected to internet?

Comment: @Freedom, yes. Typically, the computer is connected to the Internet.

Comment: then this computer can be attacked and exploited remoted and because it have no password(and presumably very poor security pratices) remotely and mess with the trains, possible with loss of life consequences

Comment: @Freedom "model railroad"

Comment: @Freedom, how does the act of having a password change anything about remote attacks?  If the computer is off, then obviously nothing can occur.  If the computer is on, and logged in, then the same security breaches would occur in any circumstance.

Comment: @StackTracer is your question about passwords, specifically, or about security in general?

Comment: @schroeder, passwords were just one facet of this.  I am interested in things that pertain to security in general as well.

Comment: @StackTracer i didn't say it was only the fact of having no password, but also combined to poor security practices AND connected to internet...easy target, even if they have no interest on your machine other than just use it as one more "cell" on a botnet

Comment: @Freedom, I'm not sure what makes you think that the other security practices are poor...  Any examples?

Comment: @StackTracer there is actually value is simply having access to an Internet-connected computer. Your CPU time can be used to break CAPTCHAs for instance. But the BIOS password, ah ah! Seriously! If a motivated adversary has physical access to your device, you're going to be in for trouble anyway... Just make sure the machine doesn't accept connections from the outside, and that the non-password-protected account isn't an admin account, and you're good to go.

Comment: @SteveDL, what if it were an admin account?  We've got a sufficiently strong (institutional) firewall that incoming connections are not an issue.

Comment: @StackTracer then any person who has access to the machine can use it to do dubious things with little accountability. It's just bad practice. You never know what people'll be up to until after they acted. If the machine is wildly available and someone is e.g. a terrorism candidate, they can use it to find information on bomb making anonymously. Or to host porn. Or to spam. Or to spread malware, etc...

Comment: @StackTracer if you haven't bother to use a password what effort you did to secure this pc after all? Likely none right? The example i would give is what Steve told, or if you don't have antivirus after all, or your windows firewall isn't even set to "public"...without a password on admin account any hacker can get admin privileges easy on PC then they can do anything.

Comment: @StackTracer having an admin account just makes it easier to install stuff permanently, set up backdoors, hide oneself... All in all you still need to restrict the "kiosk" / unprotected account to whatever it is that account should do.

Comment: @freedom, there is antivirus, a firewall, and quite likely several other firewalls outside of the computer.

Comment: @StackTracer you have supplied a LOT of details on your environment that might be nice to include in your question, including the risks you know and care about and the ones you don't

Comment: @SteveDL, I'm not sure that there's any cost if people are able to look up information anonymously on the computer.  In addition, I wish them luck if they try to host anything on it.  I don't think they'd ever make it past that firewall without authorization.

Comment: It's not really a technical, but a legal issue. You're accountable if they do something illegal and get caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protection of the machines are in most cases not against physical destruction, but against data stealing.

If others have physical access to the machine, real protection is impossible.

BIOS passwords can be easily overriden by plugging out the power, dismantling the machine at taking out the bios battery for around a half minute. This resets the bios, incuding its password. But some type of mechanical protection could be also done, for example, a sealing stick which makes the illegal dismantling unable to remain hidden.

You could maybe encrypt the hard disks, but if you do that, either

- your bootloader must contain the decrypting password,
- or you will have to physically present on every reboot.

What from the viewpoint of the security is important:

1. you must estimate the chances of the different types of possible attacks,
2. you must estimate their risk (the damage they could cause)
3. and the costs of the possible defensive mechanisms against them.

Your decisions about the protection mechanisms should be a result of the balancing of (1), (2) and (3).

In your case, if there is no real danger and the system doesn't contain really important data, but protecting it would require big effort, these arguments are against the overdosing of the security. *But, don't forget:* only you can estimate them, and it is *your* responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

Security is necessary in order to counteract "risks" to a system. You need to determine what those risks are and if "loss" in that area is acceptable.

Presumably, this train set up is not public, but in a locked building where people need a key to enter, or if allowed in, are monitored by other people watching. Yes, it is possible for someone to come in with a hammer and damage your trains, but that person is observable. An unsecured internet-connected computer potentially leaves the door open for someone to "walk in" and do damage, completely unobserved. This anonymity increases the risk that someone would do damage if they gain access (no consequences). In my opinion, it is harder to do damage with a hammer than with a computer (once access is gained).

A BIOS password is important to protect the machine against someone infecting the machine while they have physical access. There are other more important considerations if the machine is accessible by the physical public.

If it doesn't matter that someone could take over the machine, then no, security does not matter. But I suspect that it matters more than you think. But, YOU need to consider all the risks and the costs if those risks are realized.

Answer (score 1):

In general, any computer that has the capability to go online needs to be secured.  This includes not only "laptops" and other things people consider to be computers, but thermostats, sprinkler controls, and any other programmable device.

The problem may or may not be what the attacker can do to you, but also what the attacker can use your computer to do to other people.  He could log on to it and use your computer as a relay to hack someone else, or to download "illicit" materials that would be traced back to you.

A physically secured computer, with no possibility to be connected to any network, wired or wireless, still may need extra protection depending on the nature of the information it's storing.  Consider the example of a medical scanner in a clinic where famous politician Senator John Smith goes.  The doctor might scan a lump in Smith's body, and have a picture stored with his name.  A thief breaking into the clinic finds the machine, steals the picture of the lump, and it appears on the TV news the next day that "Senator Smith is Dying of Cancer, Reelection Doubtful!!"  In this case the clinic would be in clear violation of US HIPPA/Privacy laws, requiring them to keep medical information private and secured.

A real example I know of is a boutique company who does personal shopping for millionaires; they keep all their client credit card numbers on file so they can run out and buy stuff for them.  For "security" they have them all in an Excel spreadsheet, which is kept on a flash drive stored in a locked filing cabinet.  If a thief were to break in and copy the flash drive, he could easily charge tens of thousands of dollars worth of merchandise from these high rollers' credit cards.  This would similarly be a violation of the PCI Data Security Standard, and if it happened it would subject this company to bankrupting levels of fines.

Comment: However, if the computer is in a physically secured location, I would assume that a password is unnecesssary.

Comment: Passwords are always necessary.

Comment: @StackTracer Physical security provides safety from physical attacks and NOT from the IT security threats. You need different types of securities for different kind of threats. Running a machine which has lot of security vulnerabilities is never recommended even if it is locked behind the vault of a highly secured bank. What if the attacker is not interested in your $ machine but is interested in the other resources(data, performing attacks) could be worth millions of $$.

Comment: Also other way around it is also not recommended to have a highly secured machine without any physical security. Suppose the machine is highly secured with all the passwords and hell lot of encryption and so on. What if the attacker just needed the RAM of your machine because his/her machine is of the same model. ;) Maybe the attacker needs a new battery for his/her machine and he/she just steals the highly secured machine and takes the battery off and throws the rest of the highly secured and encrypted machine. ;) So as you see that different type of security prevent different threats!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the worst that could happen directly to you is your trains get damaged. If you don't mind, then you're right and security isn't necessary since you won't be bothered. If you want to save some time/energy and prevent that from occurring greatly, just add a password to the computer. It should only take a few seconds and I personally don't see why you wouldn't, provided you don't have money burning a hole in your pocket.

Comment: Not entirely true: the worst that can happen includes the loss of the computer's functionality. Imagine crypto-locker encrypting the train control software.

Comment: My reasons for not doing it are primarily that once you have a password, you have to store and distribute that password to people who should have access, and people tend to forget passwords...  In addition, most of the power supplies are manually controlled and attached to timers, so they shouldn't be able to turn on unless someone has physical access to the room.

Comment: @schroeder, the train control software is backed up and recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Having a good password to protect the system is a core safety feture. I agree 
that you should lock it under password and add. However the critick is ill fit. I agree whit the statement that its much easyer to phisicly damage the system on the location that bother to use the computer. Still the computer is vunreable from outside the LAN.